# How can i increase the background size of the image without adding much content?

Tags: html, css, amazon-ses

I am trying to add the background image on the background i am able to do it but it doesn't show the full size of the image i have used this code.
when i am trying to use background-size auto then i am getting the width right but height is small i know it depends on the content size. but still is there any way

```
<div style="background: url('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/growthfilepractice.appspot.com/o/1%20(2).jpg?alt=media&token=48244df9-a2bb-412a-81f5-854e2dbc4939');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size:500px 500px;">
  <a href ="https://github.com/" style="text-decoration: none;">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><h3 style="color: #fff;">Amarjeet Singh</h3></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

      </tr>
    </table>


  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is set as the background of your `<div>` so it's size will depend on the `width` and `height` of that `<div>`. So if the height was larger then more of the `background-image` will be show. Just to illustrate, check my code below. I have given `<div>` a `height : 600px` and the image now shows for that height.

So, in short, your background image only shows for the size of your element. the larger your element becomes the more of the image will appear.

```html
<div  class="container" 
      style=" height: 600px; /* Just to illustrate */
              position: relative;
              background: url('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/growthfilepractice.appspot.com/o/1%20(2).jpg?alt=media&token=48244df9-a2bb-412a-81f5-854e2dbc4939');
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size:500px 500px;">
  <a  class="nameAnchor" 
      href ="https://github.com/" 
      style=" text-decoration: none;
              position: absolute;
              color: white;
              left: 10px; /* Set your Left position here */
              top: 100px; /* set your top position here */
  ">
    <span>Amarjeet Singh</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: in this format is it not possible to move my name down and left i mean in next to dear for small screen and large screen?

Comment: You want your name to be in the middle of the screen irrespective of the size of that screen?

Comment: yes, i know i have to use media query but i don't think in aws see email structure media query is possible

Comment: Look to make it easier, put your name in an element and use css to move that element around using position: relative or absolute;

Comment: i am not able to understand this point put your name in element how ?

Comment: Check what I have done. I deleted the table and put your name inside an `<a>` and then put a class called `nameAnchor` to use inside css. So you can set `left: ` and `top: ` values on your css to determine the position you want you name to be at.

Comment: Please check the answer again... I have put styling inside html... update left and top positions of `<a>` to move our name to the position you want.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to set background-size : cover. This will automatically set it to the full size, if that's what you want.